# SheerResponse doesn't close

Tags: javascript, c#, html, modal-dialog, sitecore

This is part of a Sitecore 8 Update 2 MVC website, i'm extending the TreelistEx field

I've created a sheerrepsonse  modaldialog, called by this code.

```
namespace be.absi.kbs.extensions
{
   class AbsiTreeListEx : TreelistEx, IMessageHandler
   {

   void IMessageHandler.HandleMessage(Message message)
    {
        if (message == null)
        { return; }

        if (message["id"] == null)
        { return; }

        if (!message["id"].Equals(ID))
        { return; }

        var fieldInfo = _fieldInformation[message["id"]];

        switch (message.Name)
        {
            case "treelist:edit":
                var nvcEdit = new NameValueCollection { { "source", fieldInfo.Source } };
                Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.Start(this, "Edit", nvcEdit);
                break;

            case "absitreelistex:absiadd":
                var nvcAdd = new NameValueCollection {{"clientFieldId",  message["id"] } };
                Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.Start(this, "AddItem", nvcAdd);
                break;
        }
    }

    protected void AddItem(ClientPipelineArgs args)
    {
        if (args.IsPostBack)
        {
            // Get information from args
        }
        else
        {
            SheerResponse.ShowModalDialog("/QuickContact.html",true);
            args.WaitForPostBack();
        }
    }
    }
}
```

This is the html for the modaldialog:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<base target="_self">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sendResponse() {
        var o = new Object();
        o.forename = document.getElementById("FirstNameId").value;
        o.surname = document.getElementById("LastNameId").value;
        o.phone = document.getElementById("PhoneId").value;
        window.returnValue = o;
    }

    function OK() {
        sendResponse();
        window.close();
        self.close();
        document.close();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onbeforeunload="sendResponse()">
<label>First Name: </label><input type="text" id="FirstNameId" /><br />
<label>Last Name: </label><input type="text" id="LastNameId" /><br />
<label>Phone: </label><input type="text" id="PhoneId" /><br />
<a href="#" id="btnSaveImage" target="_self" onclick="OK()">
    OK
</a><br />
<input type="button" value="OK" onclick="OK()" />
```

What i want is for the user to fill in a couple of fields. When the users clicks on OK the values are returned and the window is closed.
All i am missing is the automatic close of the dialog screen.

I've tried pretty much everything i could find on the web but still it doesn't work.

Does anyone know what else i can try ?

Comment: Can you post he whole method that contains args.WaitForPostBack() and the code that handles the response. That is where the changes need to be made

Comment: Added the code @JonathanRobbins

Comment: Did you try calling `SheerResponse.CloseWindow()` within `args.IsPostPostback` part of the code?

Comment: I added it but it doesn't change anything ( the IsPostBack code is never reached )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to close the Modal dialog created by Sheerresponse:

window.parent.$('.ui-dialog-content:visible').dialog('close');